# Unknown error creating a GMaps with IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps

I'm trying to create a Google Map on a div that it's generated dinamically and IE fails to load correctly the map and throws an error while loading all the elements "unknown error at line 25 of main.js"

A test file can be found here: http://martinezdelizarrondo.com/bugs/map.html

This is the code:

```
<p>
       <img height="370" id="gMapPreview" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/
api/staticmap?
center=37.4419,-122.1419&amp;zoom=11&amp;size=500x370&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;sensor=false"
width="500" />
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initLoader()
{
       // Create a div replacing the existing img preview
       var imgMap = document.getElementById("gMapPreview"),
               dMap = document.createElement("div");
       imgMap.parentNode.replaceChild( dMap, imgMap);

       dMap.style.width = "500px";
       dMap.style.height = "370px";

       new google.maps.Map( dMap, {
                       zoom: 11,
                       center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419,-122.1419),
                       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
               });
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
   window.addEventListener("load", initLoader, false);
} else {
   window.attachEvent("onload", initLoader);
}
</script>
```

If I put the div in the original source instead of creating it with javascript then it works correctly, but for this project I want to do it this way. I've tried to do the creation of the div also before the page is finished loading, but that doesn't change the problem.

I haven't tested with IE9, just with IE8 but as this is meant to run in the public side of websites the solution should work also with IE6 & 7 as they are supported by the GoogleMaps api.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I would suggest doing something before the new:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map( dMap, {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419,-122.1419),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
```

Comment: I removed the assignment while creating the simplified sample, so that's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesn't want you to put block level element(div here) within p tag. Change p to div should fix the problem.